# How to execute SQL SELECT query in ecto migrations

Tags: migration, elixir, ecto

I am using Triplex package for multi-tenants. When I create a tenant it executes all migrations. After table creation when I execute seed migrations it gives me error:

```rb
{:error, "ERROR 42P01 (undefined_table) relation \"t2.tenants\" does not exist\n\n query: (SELECT MAX(id) from \"t2.tenants\")"}
```

on select query. If I remove select query, other queries execute successfully.

```rb
defmodule TudoChat.Repo.Migrations.SeedTableTenants do
  use Ecto.Migration

  def up do
    execute("INSERT INTO t2.tenants (\"id\", \"inserted_at\", \"name\", \"status\", \"updated_at\") values ('1', '2019-07-08 10:37:28', 'tudo_', 'active', '2019-07-08 10:37:30')")
    execute("INSERT INTO t2.tenants (\"id\", \"inserted_at\", \"name\", \"status\", \"updated_at\") values ('2', '2019-07-08 10:38:19', 'test_', 'active', '2019-07-08 10:38:22')")
    execute("(SELECT MAX(id) from \"t2.tenants\")")
  end

  def down do
  end
end
```

Please help me how to execute select query?

Comment: Did you try t2.tenants without quotes? ... Notice the INSERTs are there without quotes. Anyway, I agree with @kelu-thatsal about using the appropriate seed mechanism if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use migrations as a tool to seed your database. There is a file with seeds already if you use the default `Ecto` setup in `priv/repo/seeds.exs`. In there you are allowed to use the ecto schemas and `Repo`.

For example:

```rb
  alias TudoChat.Repo
  alias TudoChat.Tenant

  Repo.insert! %Tenant{
    name: "tudo",
    status: "active"
  }

  Repo.insert! %Tenant{
    name: "test",
    status: "active"
  }
```

This way you don't have to worry about the IDs of seeded data and timestamps as Ecto will deal with that for you.

After running migrations you also have to run one more command:

```
mix ecto.migrate
mix run priv/repo/seeds.exs
```

And if you really needed to run a query in seeds then you are also allowed to use the usual ecto queries as well.

Comment: What if I add a table and I need to have 4 specific rows in that table? Which later in another migration another table is going to be defaulted to one of these rows?

Answer (score 0):

Don't type strings with nested quotes.  Do you enjoy escaping nested quote marks?  If not, use `~s|...|` or `~s{...}` or `~s(...)` or `~s<....>` in place of the outer double quotes.  For instance:

```
iex(2)> ~s|I said, "Go home!"|
"I said, \"Go home!\""
```

Here is your statement using the `~s` sigil:

```
execute(~s|INSERT INTO t2.tenants ("id", "inserted_at", "name", "status", "updated_at") values ('1', '2019-07-08 10:37:28', 'tudo_', 'active', '2019-07-08 10:37:30')|)
```

But that line is still waay too loooong.  So, do something like this:

```
columns = ~s|("id", "inserted_at", "name", "status", "updated_at")|
values = "('1', '2019-07-08 10:37:28', 'tudo_', 'active', '2019-07-08 10:37:30')"
query = "INSERT INTO t2.tenants #{columns} values #{values}"
IO.inspect query
execute(query)
```

Here's what `query` looks like:

```
"INSERT INTO t2.tenants 
    (\"id\", \"inserted_at\", \"name\", \"status\", \"updated_at\") 
 values 
    ('1', '2019-07-08 10:37:28', 'tudo_', 'active', '2019-07-08 10:37:30')"
```

> please help me how to execute select query?
>
> ```
> execute("(SELECT MAX(id) from \"t2.tenants\")")
> ```

1) Does your database really require parentheses around a SELECT statement?

```
  |                                  |
  V                                  V
 "(SELECT MAX(id) from \"t2.tenants\")"
```

2) In your successful INSERT statement, you didn't have to quote the table name.  Does your database really require you to quote the table name in a SELECT?

```
                        |           |
                        V           V
 "(SELECT MAX(id) from \"t2.tenants\")"
```

How about:

```
execute("SELECT MAX(id) from t2.tenants")
```

However, `execute()` returns `:ok` if successful, so I'm not sure how executing that SELECT statement is helpful.  You might want to look at [Ecto.Adapters.SQL.query()](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto_sql/Ecto.Adapters.SQL.html#query/4).